# Otto subscribe and post in the same fragment does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, otto

I have three fragments in the same  activity, let says **FragmentA**, **FragmentB** and **FragmentC**

Let´s say that FragmentA sends an int to FragmentB so in the FragmentA I have:

```
    //FRAGMENT_A
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        EventBus.getBus().register(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        EventBus.getBus().register(this);
    }
   private void registerEventBus(int i) {
        EventBus.getBus().post(i);
    }
```

FragmentB received the int so:

```
  //FRAGMENT_B
  @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EventBus.getBus().register(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        EventBus.getBus().unregister(this);
    }
      @Subscribe
    public void getBusData(int data) {
       //whatever
    }
```

But now I have to send a double from FagmentB to FragmentC, I have created a new Bus class so now in the FragmentB, I have

```
//Fragment_B
       @Override
        public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            EventBus.getBus().register(this);
            EventBus2.getBus.register(this)
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();
            EventBus.getBus().unregister(this);
            EventBus2.getBus..unregister(this)
        }
          @Subscribe
        public void getBusData(int data) {
           //whatever
        }
        private void createEventBus2(double number){
         EventBus2.post(number);
        }
```

And finally the FragmentC

```
//FragmentC
 @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EventBus2.getBus().register(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        EventBus2.getBus().unregister(this);
    }
      @Subscribe
    public void getBus2Data(double data) {
      //whatever
    }
```

From FragmentA to FragmentB works perfectly but in the FragmentC I have never get the double data value.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Otto is deprecated by the way, use rxJava, really)

Comment: thanks I can not , all is project is done with Otto :(

Comment: General TIP: when subscribing to something in `onCreate()` remember to unsubscribe in `onDestroy()`. This also applies to `onCreateView()` -> `onDestroyView()`.

Comment: Are you sure `FragmentC` has already gone through it's `onCreate()` at the time when you perform `EventBus2.post(number)`?

Comment: @azizbekian ok that´s the point FragmentC is  not created at the time that I am performing the post method ...

Comment: Use handler to post an action after some time. Or use a sticky event posting (`bus.postSticky(...)`), this has a side effect after performing an orientation change in `FragmentC`.